# ASP.net Page Redirect Problem

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax

Using ASP.NET framework 3.5 I want to redirect the page in a new Blank Page using Coding :

Response.Redirect("default.aspx")

It is opening in Parent Page i.e _parent
but want to open in new web page in the current Browser and
_new is not working for opening in New Page
and have used a MultiVie

Comment: I don't think Response.Redirect does what you think it does. You need to use javascript to open a new window unless they're clicking on a link with a target set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening in new page, can only be done on the browser side using an `<a href="" target="_blank" />` Server-side code can do nothing to create new tabs or windows on the client side.

On a side note : I downvoted your question as it is pretty vague, and difficult to understand, let me know more about your problem, why you'd like to do that and then people will be able to help.